# Adding items and design on toolbar toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How to add the different type of designs and color to a toolbar and showing the value(value depends on user points) on toolbar gets updated whenever the user goes to another activity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take `RelativeLayout` inside `Toolbar` and customize it according to your requirement. Here is sample Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_plane_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:text="Submit" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```